# How can I rotate the rigged child leg with whole body?

Tags: rigging

I'm from Korea. Please be understand my low English skill.

I made a robot and put a bone in it.
All part is connected as child and the body is currently parent status.
If I rotate the body, arms and legs rotate together.
[image]

But I want to rotate the whole body with the left leg as the axis.
It's like a ballerino spinning with one foot supported.
However because the leg is child, this is spinning alone.

Please let me know the solution!!
I really appreciate it if you can help me!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could give your bones a root bone that would be the main parent of your bones (so it would be the parent of the current parent, that is probably the spone bone) and put the foot over this root when you'll want to make your rotation. Or create a bone under the foot and give your current main parent (first spine bone probably) a *Child Of* constraint that you activate (by keyframing the *Influence* value) only when you want the rotation to happen:

[image]

Comment: OH... it works, many thank you!